# Specialty stove wire and box fill

Tags: electrical, wiring

This armored wire shows 2 sets of wire crimped and a ground.

For box fill would this be considered 3 or 5?

Does this increase amprage and voltage allowances?

Is there any other circumstances a cable like this be used?

Is there a name for this?

[image]

I realize this is a specialty wire for a specified purpose.

Comment: Where in the world are you?

Comment: I beleive this is the cable that comes with Meile cooktop sold in the USA. I am in Canada. Both these countries use two hot and ground for most cooktops I have seen. I am wondering what that tip style is called and about this technic/cable. I have never seen this done before.

Comment: is this some sort of flexible whip?  Using it as permanent wiring violates 310.10(H)...

Comment: It wouldn't violate 310.10(H) if each pair of black and red are only connected on this end and not inside the cooktop.

Comment: I'd say it's 5. You're counting conductors, and even though they may be used as one, it's still two physical conductors. In a raceway or cable it's counted as two, 310.15(B)(3)(a) says "*Each current-carrying conductor of a paralleled set of conductors shall be counted as a current-carrying conductor.*"

Comment: I suspect this is done to increase ampacity while keeping the cable flexable, this thread seems to agree but I don't understand it completely.http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/110901/will-doubling-thinner-wire-in-lieu-of-thicker-wire-work Is this cable only ok because it is a manufacturer supplied one? @Dan D. How could it differ at the other end? Won't it still essentially be two wires?

Comment: Is this supplied by the cooktop maker in lieu of a cord?

Comment: Also, does this have a UL listing on it, and what is the model number of this cooktop?

Comment: Miele 30" Induction Cooktop- KM5753  this is the supplied cable.

Answer (score 2):

Since this flex whip is supplied as an integral part of the cooktop (instead of being building wiring), and consists of what I presume are fixture-type wires in a length of FMC, the conductor-paralleling provisions in 310.10(H)(1) may not apply -- UL is the one who makes the decision on whether wires in an appliance can be paralleled or not.  Furthermore, the paired wires may go to different modules in the cooktop -- it appears to be common for large electric or induction cooktops to be broken up into multiple parts for load distribution purposes.

However, there is precedent in the NEC for treating the stove wires as *tap conductors* from the branch circuit, as per 210.19(A)(3) Exception 1:

> *Exception No.1: Conductors tapped from a 50-ampere branch circuit supplying 
>   electric ranges, wall-mounted electric ovens, and counter-mounted electric 
>   cooking units shall have an ampacity of not less than 20 amperes and shall be 
>   sufficient for the load to be served. These tap conductors include any
>    conductors that are a part of the leads supplied with the appliance that are 
>   smaller than the branch-circuit conductors. The taps shall not be longer 
>   than necessary for servicing the appliance.*

In that case, they cannot actually be paralleled; I would suspect that they lead to different parts of the cooktop, even, as I mentioned above.

For box fill purposes -- I personally would count it as four conductors, even though only two current-carrying terminations are provided by the appliance manufacturer.  It isn't five, though, because only the largest EGC counts for box fill purposes as per 314.16(B)(5).

Answer (score 0):

The box fill calculation can be much higher because you're suppose to count the incoming wires too.

#### If the incoming were #8 then...

3.0 x each conductor ( for hypothetical purposes we'll say the incoming wire has one black, one red, one white, and one ground.) Also, we are counting the ground as a #12 ( 2.25 ) because that is typical size and only counting the ground once.

The whip from the oven looks to be a number #12 so well use 2.25 x 5

#### Summary

(3.0 x 3) + 2.25 = 11.25

2.25 x 4 = 9.0

Total cubic capacity = 2O.25 cu.in

So you will need a box with a minimum of 20.25 cu.in or more realistically 21 cu.in Also remember there might not be a white in the incoming wire so you box fill calculation maybe 3.0 cu.in too high

#### Concerning the parallel tapped whip...

I've came across this before and really didn't think twice about it.  It probably boils down to being financially smarter for the manufacture.

Comment: The **Only** EGC that is counted is the largest, once.